# Prevent MS Access from automatically updating/reformatting SQL query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am about to throw MS Access out the window!

Is anyone aware of an ability to stop Access from automatically reformatting my hand crafted `SQL` queries? Every time I navigate to edit the query, Access drops me on the `Query Builder` and when I select `SQL` I find Access has reformatted my query into a spaghetti mess.

The query still works, it's just not as easily readable in its new format.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered embedding the SQL in the vba code and executing from there?

Comment: Funny you should say that, I have resorted to using `vba`. It works, but I'd rather just tell Access to play nice. Thank you.

Comment: It's by design, so learn to live with it.

Comment: I can totally understand you I was not amused about this feature as well. An alternative would be to build your own query string manipulator function that cuts out the unnecessary [yourTable] statements and formats the appropriate line breaks. I persaonally never took the time to write or search for something like that so I cannot link you anything.

Comment: That is actually the query optimizer running, deciding the best plan and syntax for your query. You actually DO want it to do that. It is not a pretty print text editor. Also, do be aware because optimizer runs only for stored queries, these such queries tend to be more efficient than VBA string  SQL calls.